# Identify outliers and treat only outliers with groupby multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, group-by, outliers

I want to identify outlier with group by multiple columns and treating the outliers with 95% and 5% values. I have created a function to treat outliers like below.

```
fun_name <- function(data,x){
  qnt <- quantile(data$x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
  caps <- quantile(data$x, probs=c(.05, .95), na.rm = T)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(data$x, na.rm = T)
  data[which(data$x < (qnt[1] - H)),"x"] <- caps[1]
  data[which(data$x > (qnt[2] + H)),"x"] <- caps[2]
  return(data)
}
```

I have tried like below to impute outlier with group by:

```
total_data <- data%>%
  group_by(col1,col2,col3,col4)%>%
  mutate(fun_name(data,col5)) ## col5 is of numric type.
```

I am getting error:

```
Column `fun_name(data,col5)` is of unsupported class data.frame
```

Where am gone wrong? suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the function to :

```
fun_name <- function(x){
   qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = TRUE)
   caps <- quantile(x, probs=c(.05, .95), na.rm = TRUE)
   H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
   x[which(x < (qnt[1] - H))] <- caps[1]
   x[which(x > (qnt[2] + H))] <- caps[2]
   return(x)
}
```

and then use it as :

```
library(dplyr)
data%>% group_by(col1,col2,col3,col4)%>% mutate(col = fun_name(col5))
```

Comment: It is not imputing the outliers. Iam getting old column as it is.

Comment: @Magie It works fine with `mtcars`, dataset. `mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(col = fun_name(mpg))`. Did you assign the value backto dataframe?  `data%>% group_by(col1,col2,col3,col4)%>% mutate(col5 = fun_name(col5))
` ?. Are you sure you are having outliers in every group? If it still doesn't work please add a reproducible example.

Comment: How to identify outliers in col5 with group by multiple columns?

Comment: Name the output from `fun_name` other than the original column name and then you can directly compare. For example, in the above `mtcars` example you can get outlier row by doing `mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(col = fun_name(mpg)) %>%
  filter(mpg != col)`

Comment: Getting output but i have a doubt. My original col5 range is 0 to 551 and after imputing outliers it ranges 0 to 546. there is no much difference after imputing.

Comment: Is there any way to impute outliers better than above method?

Comment: Do you want to impute them or remove them?

Comment: I need imputation.

Comment: If you google that you'll get lot of options for imputation. It depends on the data that you have which method suits best for you but you can consider to impute outliers with `mean` or `median` values of the group.